# Any convention for handling unsupported query parameters in a REST API?

Tags: rest

I'm implementing a REST API and debating how to handle unsupported query parameters on a request URL.

The two obvious alternatives would be to (a) ignore them or (b) to treat them as invalid requests.

Right now I'm leaning toward (b), but I can see the diagnostic value that (a) would provide to client developers.

Are there any conventions in common practice, one way or another?  Or arguments to be made favoring one approach over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking they should be a 404 because they address an unknown resource.  However, I have heard of people ignoring them.  The negative impacts are not particularly significant.

The real answer though is if you are using hypermedia and URI templates/forms then clients would never send unsupported query params.  The problem is a symptom of clients constructing URIs based on out of band knowledge, which is a REST no-no in the first place :-)